# Why is the dot in a decimal replaced by comma when casted to string?

Tags: string, casting, decimal, php-7

In PHP I found out that when a decimal is printed to screen (or: when it's cast to string), the decimal separator will also be converted to a comma.
But why is that?
I haven't found any documentation about this, and I don't think casting to string takes internationalization settings into account.

Example code:

```
$var = 12.345;

var_dump($var); // Outputs: double(12.345)
var_dump((string)$var); // Outputs: string(6) "12,345"
var_dump(str_replace(',', '.', $var)); // Outputs: string(6) "12.345"
echo $var; // Outputs: 12,345
```

What causes this behavior?

---

This question applies to PHP < 8. [According to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php),

> As of PHP 8.0.0, the decimal point character is always `.`. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, the decimal point character is defined in the script's locale (category LC_NUMERIC). See the setlocale() function.

Comment: when you are usin str_replace..it is being converted in string that's why..

Comment: Uh, [no it doesn't](http://ideone.com/L6t0tJ) Converting a float to a string doesn't convert `.` to `,`

Comment: RTFM :) http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: `"I don't think casting to string takes internationalization settings into account"` :- Oh yes it does! [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) `The decimal point character is defined in the script's locale (category LC_NUMERIC). See the setlocale() function.`.

Comment: the comma (`,`) is the separator used in a number of countries. if you're experiencing this its because your locale is set to one of them.

Comment: Using:  
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '.'); 
doesn't change the output.

Comment: try `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8');`

Comment: @Piemol You really do need to start reading the manual properly :)

Comment: Yes, sorry guys. I really read the manual, and actualy also the 'note', but didn't conclude from it that the locales are actualy used... and I also didn't try it. Very stupid of me indeed.

Comment: @Piemol I took time to make you a correct answer, please read this, it can help you ... I hope ..

Answer (score 5):

If you read the manual, or check with google, you will find [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

> The decimal point character is defined in the script's locale
>   (category LC_NUMERIC)

Now, if you want to know which is the decimal point set on your sys :

```
print_r(localeconv());
```

Which returns :

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [...many other confs...]
)
```

If you want to set it use the good language : `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, $language)`

I used `fr_FR` to get a comma and `en_US` to get a dot.

You should refer to [the `setlocale()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

By the way, I don't know how to directly set the `decimal_point` key of the array returned by `localeconv()` without changing the entire LC_NUMERIC confs, if anyone knows, please edit :)

Comment: here another example but a lot of databases will go crazy if you do 50,3 instead of 50.3

        setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'German');
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'German');